# How to add description to method or class

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc

How can I add method description in Java ? I use NetBeans IDE.

[image: JavaDoc example]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use javadocs using /** comments */

For a method basically you can have

```
/**
The Desciption of the method to explain what the method does
@param the parameters used by the method
@return the value returned by the method
@throws what kind of exception does this method throw
*/
```

You can use this link for futher help http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#descriptions

Answer (score 20):

Use javadoc comments - /** This is a comment */

Check this link for detailed documentation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc

Answer (score 6):

Writing Comments above your method should do what you want
Example :

```
/** 
This method does some serious stuff 
*/
public int getN()
{
return n;
}
```

If you use javadocs it should be the description to the method.

Answer (score 3):

See the [guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) and take a look at the [source code of some of the standard Java classes](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java/?v=source).

Answer (score 2):

It's all in here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/index.html.

I'm adding this sentence because my answer above is too short for SO. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the IDE is looking for the javadoc definitions in the source files. Thus you need attach the sources to the libraries used in the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Description("method name")
methodName<String> getset(){...}

@Description("class name")
class ClassName{..}
```